# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSDictionary' in swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

while creating model for JSON like below:

```
public class ViewMoreProducts {
public var in_offers : String?
public var default_image : Default_image_viewmore?
public var product_by_language : Product_by_language_viewmore?
public var product_marchant : Product_marchant_viewmore?
}


required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {


    in_offers = dictionary["in_offers"] as? String
    if (dictionary["default_image"] != nil) { default_image = Default_image_viewmore(dictionary: dictionary["default_image"] as! NSDictionary) }
    if (dictionary["product_by_language"] != nil) { product_by_language = Product_by_language_viewmore(dictionary: dictionary["product_by_language"] as! NSDictionary) }
    if (dictionary["product_marchant"] != nil) { product_marchant = Product_marchant_viewmore(dictionary: dictionary["product_marchant"] as! NSDictionary) }

}
```

here `if (dictionary["default_image"] != nil) { default_image = Default_image_viewmore(dictionary: dictionary["default_image"] as! NSDictionary) }` i am getting error

**error:**

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull'  to 'NSDictionary'.

please do help to solve the error

edit:

```
if dictionary["default_image"] != nil {
        default_image = Default_image_viewmore(dictionary: (dictionary["default_image"] as? NSDictionary ?? [String : Any]) )}
```

then error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any].Type' to expected argument type 'NSDictionary'

Comment: Prefer using Swift Dictionary over `NSDictionary` . In general, if prefer `Class` of `NSClass` in Swift3+ when available. Use proper soft unwrap with `if let`. Don't name your class vars with a `"_"`: `Default_image_viewmore`> = `DefaultImageViewMore`. If you are using Swift4+, prefers `Codable` over manual `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: @Larme its an existing project.. here i am updating new feature in app.. thats why.. please help me to solve the error.. in remaining lines i am not getting error.. only in that line i got error.. pls do help

Comment: "Use proper soft unwrap with `if let`" still should be doable in your current code. You need to understand that using `!` means: "Crash if something goes wrong here, if it's nil (ie not castable with `as`, etc.)

Comment: I agrees with Larme: Don't use `NS...` types in Swift. Those cause the issue. `Decodable` treates `NSNull` as `nil`.

Comment: @Larme, could you pls suggest how to write `if let` i have tried some ways but.. didn't work out

Comment: `if let defaultImagesDict = dictionary["default_image"] as? NSDictionary {  self.default_image = Default_image_viewmore(dictionary: defaultImagesDict) }`. Note that `if let` is basic Swift. I suggest you read about it.

Comment: @Larme thank you, its worked.. i will read about it

Answer (score 1):

Use `as?` instead of `as!`. No `nil` check needed

```
product_by_language = (dictionary["product_by_language"] as? NSDictionary).map { Product_by_language_viewmore(dictionary: $0) }
```

For new code, please don't even use `NSDictionary` in Swift and use `Decodable` for JSON decoding.